SCORM Package Missing Learner ID Error on Connecteam LMS, Works Fine on Other Platforms
I'm currently using RXD Rustici service to generate SCORM packages and uploading them to Connecteam’s Storyline LMS. While the upload process completes successfully, I encounter an issue when trying to run the course: it returns an error stating that the "learner ID is missing."
Interestingly, the same SCORM packages work fine on other LMS platforms, so it seems to be an issue specific to Connecteam's LMS.
Steps I’ve taken:
Uploaded the SCORM package to Connecteam's LMS.
Tried running the course, but encountered the error regarding the missing learner ID.
Verified that the SCORM package requires learner details for proper execution.
Attached: Screenshot of the error message.
Question:
Has anyone experienced similar issues with SCORM packages in Connecteam’s Storyline LMS?
Are there any specific settings or configurations in Connecteam’s LMS that I might be missing?
Could there be an issue with how Connecteam handles SCORM packages compared to other LMS platforms?
Any insights or suggestions on how to address this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I have tried the following steps:
Uploading the SCORM Package: I uploaded the SCORM package generated using RXD Rustici service to Connecteam’s Storyline LMS. The upload was successful without any errors.
Running the Course: When I attempt to run the course, I encounter an error indicating that the "learner ID is missing."
Testing on Other LMS Platforms: I tested the same SCORM package on various other LMS platforms, and it functions as expected without any issues related to learner details.
What I Expected:
I expected the SCORM package to run smoothly on Connecteam’s LMS, just as it does on other LMS platforms. I anticipated that the learner ID would be correctly handled by the LMS, allowing the course to function properly.
Current Issue:
Despite the package working fine on other platforms, it fails on Connecteam’s LMS with a learner ID error. I’m seeking guidance on whether there are specific configurations or settings in Connecteam’s LMS that need to be adjusted to resolve this issue.
Connecteam LMS

Hi, in this way, your question is off-topic. Too many questions. Please read how to ask
